# Drop column in Impala

Tags: hadoop, hive, impala, alter-table

I want to drop the whole column 'index' (column name and values) in Impala:

| index | case_id | customer_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | xxx56 |

I used this code:

```
ALTER TABLE DBName.Tablename
DROP COLUMN index;
```

The result is like this:

| case_id | customer_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |

How can I solve this?

Comment: What is the actual problem?  Does your code even run?

Answer (score 0):

Dropping a column with `ALTER TABLE mytab DROP COLUMN col` will alter only metadata and underlying data remains intact. Which means you got the columns shifted although data is intact.

Only solution is to backup, drop and recreate the table.

```
create table DBName.Tablename_tmp as select case_id,    customer_id from DBName.Tablename; -- just backup table with new structure.
drop table DBName.Tablename;
create table DBName.Tablename as select * from DBName.Tablename_stg;
```